# How to redirect a virtual page (e.g. /blog) to the home page?

Tags: url-rewriting, pages, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my to reach my website's main page when entering an url like:

http://example.com/blog

However, I can't seem to get it to work with a typical rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog$ /
```

I'm always taken to my site's 404 page.

Works fine if I specify a specific file (e.g. "/foo.html") instead of "/", but "/index.php" doesnt't work.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Do you really want to redirect the browser, or just stay at the same URL but display what would be displayed at the front page? So should the browser address bar show `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com/blog/`? (Use `@Jan` when you reply in a comment and I get a notification)

Comment: @Jan It should show example.com/blog if possible, but I don't mind if it doesn't.

Comment: So you want the same information at `http://example.com/blog/` and at `http://example.com/`? Or a static page on the latter?

Comment: I want the same information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect has to be a 301, not an internal request.  Otherwise WordPress will search dor a page named **blog**.
And you don’t need mod_rewrite.

```
# Apache 1.3 needs a complete URL
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/blog$ http://example.com/

# Apache 2.x needs just the path
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/blog$ /
```

Answer (score 0):

What would be at **example.com**? if your using WordPress as CMS and if you want to display your weblogs at **example.com/blog** just create static front page. See codex page for more information - [Creating a Static Front Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra rewrite rule to *WordPress* (not to *Apache*, via the `.htaccess` file) to make `/blog/` render the latest blog posts:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse17663_init' );
function wpse17663_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( 'blog/?$', 'index.php?post_type=post', 'top' );
}
```

Flush the rewrite rules after you add this code (by visiting the *Permalinks* page, for example).